# Visual Studio Code ignores settings.json field: python.pythonPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to get my `settings.json` file to influence how python is invoked in VSCode when selecting "Run Code" (default hot key `Ctrl + Alt + N`), my user `settings.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.jediEnabled": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "workbench.tree.indent": 24,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "untitled",
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultKeybindings": false,
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
    "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": false,   
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Jedi",
}
```

yet when I run my python file, *not debug it*, it is showing:

```
[Running] python -u "path/to/file.py"
```

when I am expecting (as I set `python.pythonPath` in `settings.json`):

```
[Running] /usr/bin/python3 -u "path/to/file.py"
```

Why is my `settings.json` file key `python.pythonPath` having no effect on how my code is invoked?

Among other important reasons, my python code doesn't even run as `python` invokes python 2 on my machine when my code is written in python 3.

VSCode version:

```
Version: 1.47.3
Commit: 91899dcef7b8110878ea59626991a18c8a6a1b3e
Date: 2020-07-23T15:51:39.791Z (1 mo ago)
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-112-generic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [vscode-python-DeprecatePythonPath](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments), `python.pythonPath` setting is being removed from all 3 scopes - **User**, **workspace**, **workspace folder**. The path to the workspace interpreter will now be stored in VS Code’s **persistent storage** instead of the settings.json file. That's why your setting has no effect on code execution path. You can change the value stored in workspace settings using **Python: Select Interpreter** command, or add the setting in **User** settings.json:

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath":
```

Comment: So it's _only now_ stored in a persistent storage? Was that change perhaps motivated by an ill-conceived conviction that `settings.json` was *not* kept in a persistent location and users liked to manually restore all VS Code settings after each application restart?